# Procedure Recursion and Stacking

Tags: recursion, stack, runtime, semantics

To model the run-time semantics of procedures, it is known that a stack is generally needed. 
1. If the language does not allow procedure recursion, do we have to have stacks? 
2. If the language does allow procedure recursion, but a recursive call can only happen at the end of a procedure, do we have to have stacks?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. However if the language is turing complete you can simulate one if you want. Eg. Brainf**k doesn't have a stack and I have made a [LISP1 interpreter](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) with it that supports procedures and macros.
2. It depends. Traditionally you need a way to have multiple nested arguments and that is a stack by definition. If your procedures have no arguments and only can call something else in the end of it's code It's almost as if procedures give less value than a goto would. However if you mean tail instead of end then it would be just as good as a goto without arguments.